# Install BigBluebutton from your forked GitHub Repo, with your settings not the original repository

Tags: github, openedx, bigbluebutton

I create the settings on the git repository so i don't have to config again after the installation. The idea is to install from the github  repo.

But, in the case of bigBluebutton, it gets the files from 
https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh . and when i check the file there is no reference to any github repository... so is not about changing urls only.

Could you put me in the right direction?

I want to do the same with open-edx

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked recently in our bigbluebutton-setup forums

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigbluebutton-setup/NKMGDlqdHmk/DP7Tb0C3CgAJ

The short answer is we don't have any script that can update a production BigBlueButton instance with changes made to a forked version of BigBlueButton in GitHub.  You would need to follow our docs to re-deploy the components that you update.